# Set static property in generic class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

Is it possible set static property in generic method?

For example: all my entities have some shared columns (`CreateDateTime`, `CreateUser` etc) - how can I implement the method?

```
 public virtual void Insert(T entity)
 {
        Dbset.Add(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need a static property for this? If you want to implement some common logic, use generic repository or set the common property values in model configuration.

Comment: you are correct about datetime I can override OnModelCreating but what about createduser  I need to pass some value on reposittory is it possiible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `BaseEntity` class which all of your entities are derived from and add your shared properties to it.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { set; get;}
    public string CreatedUser { set; get;}
}

public class YourEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { set; get;}
}
```

and add a constraint to your generic method, so you can set `CreatedDateTime` and `CreatedUser`

```
public virtual void Insert(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    entity.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    entity.CreatedUser = CURRENT_USER;

    Dbset.Add(entity);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```